# Software to adjust my screen's brightness based on what programs are in view

Tags: windows, gratis, display

I'm looking for software that can automatically adjust my screen's brightness based on what programs are currently in view. Here are my requirements,

- Compatiable with Windows 10
- Works with Windows brightness settings
- Ability to set default brightness
- Ability to set specific brightness with certain programs
- Gratis

Some features that are not requirements but wanted are,

- Works with multiple monitors
- Compatiable with Linux and OSX